# Directional derivatives and continuitity of multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

I am currently learning multivariate function calculus and trying to figure out the relationship between differentiability, continuity, and directional derivatives. My main question is if a directional derivative exists in all directions at a point $(x_0, y_0)$ and satisfies the equation

$$D_{\vec{u}}f(x_0, y_0) = \nabla f\cdot \vec{u}$$
(where $\vec{u}$ is the direction unit vector)

then is f continuous? I already know that the inverse is not true, as a function can be continuous and not have directional derivatives(or even partial derivatives), but I can't seem to find a good counterexample nor a proof for this statement. (I also found a counterexample for a directional derivative existing but the function not being continuous, but strangely all of those examples do not satisfy the equation above)

Note: this is the definition of directional derivative that I am dealing with:

$$D_{\vec{u}}f = \lim_{h-> 0}\frac{f(x_0+ah, y_0+bh)-f(x_0, y_0)}{h}$$ (where $\vec{u}=(a,b)$ and is a unit vector)

and am using the epsilon-delta definition for continuity.

Comment: In this case $(a,b)$ are the coordinates of $u$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Looks like I forgot to mention that in the note. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E=\text{graph}(x\mapsto x^2)\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, i.e the set of all pairs $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and such that $y=x^2$, and define $f=\chi_E$ (i.e $f(x,y)=1$ if $(x,y)\in E$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise). Then,

- $f$ is not continuous at the origin (there are sequences converging to $(0,0)$ along which the limit is $1$, and others along which the limit is $0$)
- all directional derivatives at the origin exist and are equal to $0$ (exercise!), so the equation you cite is trivially satisfied (both sides vanish).

So, the answer to your question is no, this is not even enough to guarantee continuity.

Comment: Ah that seems like a good counterexample I was searching for. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: in fact my second bullet point can be strengthened: for each $v\in\Bbb{R}^2$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $t\in (-\delta,\delta)$, we have $f(tv)=0$. In words, along each line through the origin, there is a small portion of it around the origin, on which the function vanishes identically. (Now this may sound like $f$ vanishes identically near the origin, but that’s not true, since the $\delta$ depends on the $v$).

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general as partial derivatives existing does not imply the existence of the total derivative (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative). A pathological example is

$$f(x,y)= \cases{ \displaystyle\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},&$(x,y) \neq (0,0)$\cr 0,&$(x,y)=(0,0)$}.$$

**However, if the partial derivatives are continuous in a neighbourhood of a point. Then the total derivative exists at that point and the function is also continuous at that point.**

[image]

Comment: this is one of the standard examples, but it’s not pathological enough, since (by homogeneity) we have that for all $v\in\Bbb{R}^2$, $D_vf(0)=f(v)$, meaning the dependence on $v$ is not linear, as requested by OP.